# Handling open url for Facebook Login with Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm using the new [Facebook Swift SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift) instead of the Objective C SDK.

Previously, the `openURL` in `AppDelegate.swift` had to be implemented. However, Facebook's Swift tutorial doesn't cover this part.

The following is logged:

`Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: Shoppie.AppDelegate`

But my implementation doesn't work:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: nil)
    if (url.scheme?.hasPrefix("fb"))! {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: nil)
    } else {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: nil)
    }
    return false
}
```

Due to:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'
```

I installed the Swift SDK by adding the following to my `Podfile`:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

And running `pod install`.

I can't find what the updated code should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their documentation is a bit lacking, but they do provide a good sample app in their github repository. see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/blob/master/Samples/Catalog/Sources/AppDelegate.swift

Here's the code (Swift 3) I'm using to intergate the SDK into my apps:

```
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    if let _ = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FacebookAppID") as? String {
      return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                                       open: url,
                                                       sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                       annotation: annotation)
    }

      return false
    }

  @available(iOS 9.0, *)
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

    if let _ = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FacebookAppID") as? String {
      return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
    }

      return false
  }
}
```

FYI - the facebook swift library is basically just a wrapper to their standard objective-c library.

Comment: Ah, `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` was renamed to `SDKApplicationDelegate`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'` issue by adding the following to my `Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Login works after making these changes.

It seems the Facebook Swift SDK is still in beta, and the tutorials are yet to be updated. ([Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/64))